# C# fluent nhibernate question

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, proxy, lazy-loading

I am trying to globally disable `Fluent NHibernate` *lazy-loading* features, but even after:

```
LazyLoad.Never();
DefaultLazy.Never();
```

`NHibernate` in my test code keeps telling the following:

```
NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException:
The following types may not be used as proxies:

XXXX: method YYYY should be 'public/protected virtual'
      or 'protected internal virtual'
```

I don't want to mark arbitrary methods of my classes as virtual if I've disabled lazy loading. Does this have a solution or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: This post talks about the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278110/nhibernate-exception-method-add-should-be-public-protected-virtual-or-protect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn Lazy loading off, then Nhibernate will try to retrieve all the associate properties (eg:- Person class has a Car association property) as soon as you fetch person from the database.

To populate the car property Nhibernate creates a proxy of the person class by inheriting person class and overriding the Carpark property.

If However, your car property is non virtual, Nhibernate will see if Lazy Loading is on and if it could escape loading the property, however that is not the case with your app and hence the exception.

For some light reading: 
http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/